# No viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type (vectors)

Tags: c++, function, vector, compiler-errors, return

I am trying the hackerrank question and they gave said to give the output as "Print two space-separated integers describing the respective numbers of times the best (highest) score increased and the worst (lowest) score decreased." Now, whenever I try to give only cout, it throws an error saying "Non-void function does not return a value". Now normally, I used to give return 0 in these situations but here it is saying "No viable conversion from returned value of type 'int' to function return type." I really don't know how to either return int in a vector function or simply put, how to return the answers back to the compiler.

Here is my function

```cpp
vector<int> breakingRecords(vector<int> scores) {
    int min=0,max=0;
    int maxUpdate=0;
    int minUpdate=0;
    for(int i=0;i<scores.size();i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            min=max=scores[0];
            break;
        }
        if(scores[i]>scores[i-1])
        {
            max=scores[i];
            maxUpdate++;
        }
        else if(scores[i]<scores[i-1])
        {
            min=scores[i];
            minUpdate++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: If my logic has any error then please don't correct it. I want to find errors in my logic on my own just help me get my code run.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect to convert a single integer value `0`, in your `return` statement,  to a `vector<int>`, which is what the function is declared to return? How do you expect this to work, in C++?

Comment: I don't. I understand what you are saying but I was just trying my luck. Is there any way in which I can print minUpdate and maxUpdate without returning anything else ?

Comment: If you don't what to return "anything else". that's what `void` is for. The real problem here is that useless online coding/hacking/competition sites, like "hackerrank" consist of just a random list of programming puzzles, without a single paragraph of anything that actually attempts to teach C++ in any organized manner. The only place you will be able to learn how to implement these kinds of algorithms would be a C++ textbook. And not hackerrank. So, if your goal is to learn C++, where do you think will be the best place for you to learn from?

Comment: it is from a book but these places are better visually and they can give a sense of competition. Anyways, not here to debate about this but I found the answer. I made a vector array and placed maxupdate and minupdate in it and returned it. Worked like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set your function to return vector type of object, so returning 0 or not returning anything is unacceptable. You basically have 3 options here:

1. Set your function as a void type - then you can only "cout" and you're good, or
   even nothing at all.
2. Return "scores" itself without actually using it outside your function
3. Set your function as an int type - to return 0, if necessary.

Good Luck!

Comment: 1.) error occurs in the main file of their code
2.) did but then it is returning the array which was given in the question. I want to print minUpdate and maxUpdate
3.) Same as 1st

Comment: 1) There is no actual reason for an error unless you've used the function wrong.. may you add the function calling from main? 2) Why bother about it returning the array, you don't have to *do* anything with it, (the printing should obviously be inside the function. Just add cout<<minUpdate <<" "<<maxUpdate)

Answer (score 2):

Your probleme come from the return type, you wan't to return a `std::vector<int>` but you are actualy returning an `int`:

```cpp
return 0;
```

To fix it, just change the return value `0` to a `std::vector<int>` value or change your return type to `int` instead of `std::vector<int>`.